# Get all values of a particular attribute from xml using python

Tags: python, xml

I need to get all values of a particular attribute. The tag name of that attribute might be different and the attribute might be at any level in the xml tree (root level / child level / etc.).
Consider the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <college name ="xyz"/>
    <university>
        <college name = "abc1" id = "a"/>
        <college name = "abc2" id = "b"/>
        <sub-univ>
            <sub-univ-col name = "sfd"/>
        </sub-univ>
    </university>
    <school name = "asdf"/>enter code here
```

How do I get the value of "name" attribute from all the xml tags.?
XML file which I has much more levels than the example stated above. Is there any way to get the values without parsing at every level?

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward in any parser that supports `XPath`.  For example, `lxml`:

```
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(that_xml_you_gave)

doc.xpath('//@name')
Out[208]: ['xyz', 'abc1', 'abc2', 'sfd', 'asdf']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Beautiful Soup, this becomes pretty easy:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <college name ="xyz"/>
    <university>
        <college name = "abc1" id = "a"/>
        <college name = "abc2" id = "b"/>
        <sub-univ>
            <sub-univ-col name = "sfd"/>
        </sub-univ>
    </university>
    <school name = "asdf"/>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
names = [tag.get('name') for tag in soup.find_all()]
print(names)
```

Result:

```
['xyz', None, 'abc1', 'abc2', None, 'sfd', 'asdf']
```

Note that we use `tag.get(...)` because some of the tags don't have a `name` attribute. Alternatively, you could instead do:

```
names = [tag['name'] for tag in soup.find_all() if tag.has_attr('name')]
```

With result:

```
['xyz', 'abc1', 'abc2', 'sfd', 'asdf']
```